# Xcode Adding multi image in a table cell that can scroll Horizontal

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview, uitableview

Im making a restaurant app that allow me show 1 restaurant with many images in a table cell. I know how to customize the table cell. 
Problem is I dont know how to add many picture into a table cell that can scroll Horizontal to view the image one by one. I added a scrollview in a table cell then add image inside the scroll but it not work when i scroll the image.

Can anybody help to give me some hint to do this?

Thanks so much,
Quang

Comment: I think you should remove the pan gesture from the tableview

Comment: thanks jcesar for your reply, can you please help to detail what the pan gesture is?

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIScrollView on top of the UITableViewCell, then fill the scroll view with images. There are plenty of tutorials on the interwebs about how to do this.

Comment: Hi Erway,
Thanks for the reply. Yes I tried your solution already, I can make a  simple scroll view then fill with images and its works but it's not the case when i add the scroll into a table cell.
Can you please help with more details?
thanks

Comment: Is the `UITableViewCell`'s `userInteractionEnabled` property set to YES?

Comment: Yes it's set to YES as defaul, if I add the scroll in on the main view it will work with setContentOffset. But when I add the scroll in the table cell, i don't sure where to add the setContenOffset, I added it in Table row create in cellForRowAtIndexPath...